# How to cause a compile error/warning, when a protected (or abstract) method in the parent class is removed and sub-classes have implemented it

Tags: java, oop, java1.4

Let's say you you have a class called Vehicle that outlines a protected (could also be abstract) method called speed. And, the sub class Car overrides that method to define its own implementation.

Now, assume that the need to have a speed method in the Vehicle class is no longer required (let's say all vehicles will be stationary for the whatever reason).

If I remove the method speed from Vehicle, I would like to throw a compile error so that so that the developer who has removed the method knows that sub class(es) are potentially relying on it to perform certain actions.

Technically speaking a compile error is not needed, but some sort of notification that acts as a hurdle when such re factoring is happening. Is there a programming pattern that can be employed to handle such a situation?

UPDATE: I am using Java 1.4 (Sorry!)

Answer (score 2):

The `@Override` annotation is expressly for this purpose.

If you're not using Java 1.5+, then no, although you *could* use AOP to instrument those methods to throw an exception, or just use reflection and classpath scanning to go over all subclasses and check for the presence of said method.

Comment: I think _annotations_ were added only in 1.5, which suggests that there's just no way to do this, really, in 1.4.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's why I edited the question after the OP clarified. AOP is not intrinsically related to annotations, nor is classpath scanning.

Answer (score 1):

If it's abstract, then there is no implementation that can be removed from the parent class, and your risk comes down to new subclasses not implementing it.  If it's protected and defined in the parent, there are two cases that should already throw compiler errors if the parent implementation is removed.

1) A subclass calls that method without defining its own implementation.  Method does not exist.

2) A subclass defines the method, but includes a call to super.  Again, the method does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Override` annotation for methods in subclases.
Once you remove the method from a base-class, tools like *Eclipse* and *javac* will issue a warining for those *no-longer-overriding* methods.

**Edit:** While you cannot use `@Override` before Java 1.5.0, there is a tool called [`xdoclet`](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/index.html). Back in the days of J2EE and EJB 2.1 this was used to "simulate" annotations and do *magical* things with code based on javadoc-like markers. Look at it, maybe you can use it.

**Edit 2:** In Java 1.4.x, you can also use JavaDoc tag `{@inheritDoc}` for this kind of verification. Instead of annotating your method with `@Override` annotate it with `@inheritDoc`, like this:

```
public class MyAwesomeClass extends BaseClass
{
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    protected void myAweSomeMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, if you change the `myAweSomeMethod` signature in `BaseClass`, or remove it, you will get warnings from JavaDoc tool, similar to this:

> /home/npe/java-tests/MyAwesomeClass.java:4: warning - @inheritDoc used but myAwesomeMethod does not override or implement any method.

Comment: Sorry, using Java 1.4 I have updated the question to reflect that

Comment: I've updated the answer with a JavaDoc hack. See if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `super.speed()` in nested classes and leave this method empty in parent. If you delete now this method in parent, you'll have an Exception. But there is a disadvantage - you must call it from all overrided methods. Try it, perhaps this will help you